# An example of non simple group which is also a Lie group such that $G$ is a connected Lie group and has no non trivial normal Lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, examples-counterexamples, simple-groups

I want to know if there exist a non simple group (as abstractl group) $G$ such that $G$ is a connected Lie group and has no non trivial normal Lie subgroup. I have tried some obvious examples like general linear group and some of its subgroups, I am not able to find out.

Comment: There are no such groups. But a proof is somewhat involved. One first reduces to the case of simple Lie groups (using Levi-Malcev decomposition). Then one proves that centerless connected simple Lie groups are simple as abstract groups. The proof that I know uses BN pairs, but maybe there is an easier argument.